# Why do we quotient only by equivalence relations?

Tags: definition, equivalence-relations

In textbooks, I've always seen the notion of quotient set defined with equivalence relations, that is: if $R$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, we can define the quotient set $X/R = \{[x]_R \mid x \in X\}$ where $[x]_R = \{y \in X \mid (x,y) \in R\}$ is the equivalence class represented by $x$.

However, isn't the definition of $X/R$ also valid even if $R$ is not an equivalence relation on the set $X$? For instance, could it be possible to define
$\Bbb{R}\,/\!≤$ $\;= \{[x]_{≤} \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$,
where $[x]_{≤} = ]-\infty, x]$ (and $≤$ the usual order on the real numbers)?

Thank you!

Comment: Quotient, by definition, is an operation that sets pairs of elements of a set *equal* to each other. I'm not sure how you came up with your definition of $\mathbb{R}/\leq$. What should a quotient be, in your mind?

Comment: Is your idea useful? Quotient sets partition the set $X$ into (disjoint) subsets with elements in each subset having some property that makes them in some sense equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand your question. such a definition of *what*?  Of course we could and do define such sets.  What's the question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My question was precisely to know if we sometimes define $X/R$ where $X$ is a set, and $R$ a relation on $X$ (not necessarily an equivalence relation). Thanks to your comments, I see that this is _possible_, but probably useless.

Comment: We can always and do define such a set.  We just don't use that notation.  But you could if you defined it.  I do prefer smcc's reaction to mine, however in that [x] \in X/R has significance into what sort of objects the sets [x],[y] etc in X/R are whereas there is little significance to (-infty,x) subset R and (-infty,y) subset R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a nice idea. For any relation $R$ on a set $X$, you might more generally define

$$X / R \equiv \{ \{ y \in X : y R x\} : x \in R \}$$

(In order theory, these are related to the notion of *ideals*.)

This construction has the property that if $R$ is a partial order on $X$, then $X/R \cong X$, and if $R$ is an equivalence relation then $X/R$ is the optimal way of dividing $X$ into groups such that (1) each partition contains members that are all $R$-related to each other, and (2) each $x\in X$ appears in exactly one group.